# run "altinstall"ed python2.4 for nodejs install

Tags: python, linux, node.js, centos

i'm new to linux, please bear with me.

i'm trying to get nodejs running on my server, but because the default python version is 2.3, and nodejs requires at least 2.4 to install, i have done a "altinstall" of python2.4.

the python should be installed correctly, i can run it like this /usr/local/bin/python2.4, and when i do a version check -V, it shows Python 2.4.

okay so now i'm trying to continue with the nodejs installation, at the `./configure` step. the problem is i'm not sure how to actually get the script to use the altinstall-ed python2.4 binary.

i've tried

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node -with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.4

./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.4
```

but they don't work. i still keep getting this error

```
NameError: name 'set' is not defined
```

how do i force the script to use this "altinstall"ed python2.4?

Comment: Please update your server if it's still using Python 2.3. Even 2.4 is horribly outdated. Python 2.3 was initially released in **2003**; Python 2.4 in **2004**. Do you really want to use a server which is running 7-year-old versions (the newer versions of 2.3 and 2.4 just fixed bugs)?!

Comment: yeah it is a really old VPS, running on centOS4+. but it's one of the cheaper ones i could find, and i'm kinda experimenting with stuff on it so... but yea thanks for the advice. will upgrade when i'm more confident :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the sources, and a `./configure --help` in the node sources said nothing about specifying your python, so you could try these slightly hackier tricks:

An `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.4` before you execute `configure` could work.

It that doesn't work, a symlink in a custom `~/bin` directory (or similarly named if it already exists) to the desired Python:

Try creating a `bin/` directory in your `$HOME` path:

```
~$ mkdir bin     # <- in your home path
```

Then link the Python 2.4 executable into this directory:

```
~$ cd bin
~/bin$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.4 python
```

Then at the node source tree, run `configure` with you `~/bin` directory as the first directory in your `$PATH`:

```
[your node.js source path]$ PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH ./configure
```

Comment: I got this error

`-bash: /usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin=/root/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin: No such file or directory`

Comment: ok fixed it! the solution is rather simple :-

i just looked into the `./configure` code and found this it referenced a script `/tools/waf-light`, which had the header `#!/usr/bin/env python`. 

obviously it was using the default python command. changed it to `#!/usr/bin/env python2.4` and did the ./configure again, and it went through! :)